# How can I execute the getHead function

Tags: php, function, curl

I will execute the getHead function from https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1a9eb381f6a5f260bd20

This is what I have tried but it doens´t work:

```
<?php
require('MultiCurlHead.php');

$urls = array("http://www.google.com/",
              "http://www.facebook.com/",
              "http://www.yahoo.com/");

getHead($urls);
?>
```

How I can get the output the website data to a variable or array?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: `$response = getHead($urls);` ... should contain an array looking at the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function `getHead($urls)`, but you're not doing anything to display the result of the function call.

You can assign the output of the call to `getHead($urls)` to a variable, then use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to display the result.

Here's a simple example of what's happening when you're returning a result:

```
<?php
function square($num)
{
    return $num * $num;
}
square(4);  // This is what you're doing. This outputs nothing.
echo square(4); // outputs '16'.
?>
```

Interesting read:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: Thanks that works. I add this line: ```var_dump (getHead($urls));```